# Dynamic Chromosome Length in Genetic Algorithms

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

My inquiry concerns the length of chromosomes employed in genetic algorithms (GA), and more broadly in other classes of evolutionary algorithms.

The chromosome length is fixed throughout a GA's run. However, some work has explored the benefits of altering a related GA parameter: the size of the GA population, which is allowed to vary in size (increase or decrease) from one generation to the next in order to better explore and exploit the search space.

My question is now: given that the population size can change, is there any benefit to altering chromosome size? I haven't really come across any work on this.

I imagine this would have applications in things like cruise stopovers and finding alternate routes to a given destination.

Adding another city for instance in a run of the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) using GA would lead to an increase in the search space that must be explored. Take for instance a tour with 10 cities: the size of the search space is 10! = 3628800. Adding an addition city would mean that there are now an additional 36288000 (11! - 10!) tours to consider.